# Ubuntu video lens

Tags: 12.04, unity, video, youtube, lenses

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.I have a problem about unity video lens.When I use filter ; for an example YouTube and just searched about fast and furious , it appears very different search results than the search results from YouTube site for the same topic.I want to appear the same result on video lens , that appears in YouTube site.I checked this for other sites like daily motion and I found the same problem.
Also, when I searched without a filter, I appears very unrealted or least related ones.Mostly Indian Videos.

Please help me in this problem. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it only supports YouTube Shows, Movies and Educations, so most YouTube results won't show up in the default Ubuntu video lens.It is the reason.[enter link description here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/alternative-youtube-video-lens-updated.html)